# Retrieve two different fields for a joined table with repeated foreign key

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g, foreign-keys

I have a table that reuses a foreign key and I'd like to join a different value for each case.  The first table describes a drug dosing activity.  It has ID's that point to drugs, routes, vehicles, etc... The confusing thing is that it reuses the Unit ID which is a foreign key in a single description table.

GROUPS (Simplified)

```
GROUP_NO    DRUG      DRUG_AMOUNT     DRUG_UNIT     CHECK_UNIT
   1        568           5               7              5
   2        689           1               7              5
   2        568           5               7              5
   3        19            0.5            10             
   4        984           10             10              5
```

UNITS (Simplified)

```
UNIT_ID      UNIT_DESCR
   5         kg
   7         mg
   10        mL
```

I'd like to generate a query that returns a row for each drug dose for all groups.  I can do everything but the units.  I'd like to use a CASE statement to display the dosing units.  The select statement would look something like this:

```
'DOSE UNITS' =
CASE
WHEN CHECK_UNIT IS NULL THEN DRUG_UNIT_DESCR
ELSE CONCAT(DRUG_UNIT_DESCR+'/'+CHECK_UNIT_DESCR)
END
```

I'm trying to get the results to look like such for this example:

RESULT

```
GROUP_NO      DRUG          DRUG_AMOUNT     'DOSE UNITS'
    1       HelpsAlot           5              mg/kg
    2       HelpsMore           1              mg/kg
    2       HelpsAlot           5              mg/kg
    3       DoesNothing         0.5            mL
    4       WhoKnows            10             mL/kg
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two joins, one for each key:

```
select g.*,
       'DOSE UNITS' = (CASE WHEN CHECK_UNIT IS NULL THEN du.UNIT_DESCR
                            ELSE CONCAT(du.UNIT_DESCR+'/'+cu.UNIT_DESCR)
                       END) 
from groups g left outer join
     units cu
     on g.check_unit_id = cu.unit_id left outer join
     units du
     on g.drug_unit_id = du.unit_id
```

Comment: Groups!!! How could I forget about groups!!!  Still a noob to SQL.  I'll give it a run.

Answer (score 0):

assuming drug_unit is always populated

```
select group_no, drug, drug_amount, 
'dose units' =
case
when check_unit is null then u1.unit_descr
else concat(u1.unit_descr+'/'+ u2.unit_descr)
end
from groups g inner join units u1
on g.drug_unit = u1.unit_id
left join units u2 
on g.check_unit = u2.unit_id
```